# How to set array specific values in state React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I've an array in my state and I want to set array specific values. Kindly let me know to setState

```
constructor(){
  super()
  this.state = {
     data: [
       {
         name: '',
         email: '',
         phone: ''
       }
     ]
  }
}

<TextInput
   style={styles.inputTextCol}
   value={this.state.data.name}
   onChangeText={(value) => this.setState({ data[0].name: value  })}
/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a function that handles it, copy array, change value and update state.
You also cant add `value={this.state.data.name}` since data is array.

```
const handleOnChange = value => {
    const data = [...this.state.data];
    data[0].name = value;
    this.setState({data});
}

const { data } = this.state;
<TextInput
   style={styles.inputTextCol}
   value={data[0].name}
   onChangeText={handleOnChange}
/>
```

Here's the answer what you should do when you have three inputs. You dont need to add three methods, instead put a `name` in your text input and pass the whole `event` to the `handleOnChange`. So you can get the name of the input and just update that element in state:

```
state = {
  data: {
    name: "",
    email: "",
    phone: ""
  }
};

const handleOnChange = ({ target }) => {
  const { name, value } = target;
  this.setState(prevState => ({
    data: { ...prevState.data, [name]: value }
  }));
};

const { name, email, phone } = this.state.data;
return (
  <React.Fragment>
    <TextInput
      style={styles.inputTextCol}
      name="name"
      value={name}
      onChange={handleOnChange}
    />
    <TextInput
      style={styles.inputTextCol}
      name="email"
      value={email}
      onChange={handleOnChange}
    />
    <TextInput
      style={styles.inputTextCol}
      name="phone"
      value={phone}
      onChange={handleOnChange}
    />
  </React.Fragment>
);
```

Comment: I've three textboxes one for emaol and another one is for phone. what about that? I also have to create function for both of them too?

Answer (score 0):

```
const data = [...this.state.data]; //we are making copy of array instead using its reference
data[0].name  = 'changedValue'; //then on our copy we make changes
this.setState({data}}; //then we set changed array back to the state.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
constructor(){
  super()
  this.state = {
     data: [
       {
         name: '',
         email: '',
         phone: ''
       }
     ]
  }
}

const handleChange = (value) => {
  let data = [ ...this.state.data ]
  data[0].name = value
  this.setState({data})
}

<TextInput
   style={styles.inputTextCol}
   value={this.state.data.name}
   onChangeText={(value) => handleChange(value)}
/>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<TextInput
   style={styles.inputTextCol}
   value={this.state.data.name}
   onChangeText={(value) => this.setState({ data: [{...this.state.data[0], name: value}] })}
/>
```

Comment: Please add explanation as well along with the code, to make it understandable how it will solve the problem.